# SQL - Ordering records with the same timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, sql-order-by, teradata

I have some data in Teradata which shows how people are using a toggle switch. The toggle is ON/OFF so obviously each record in my data should be different as the toggle is switched between ON and OFF e.g. row 1 should be ON, row 2 should be OFF, row 3 should be ON etc.

The problem is, the timestamp in the data is only to the second. So if a toggle has been turned ON and then OFF within the same second there's no way to order the data correctly. There is an EVENT_ID value but it's not perfectly sequential unfortunately.

I need the events ordered correctly as I use them in an ordered analytical function - knowing what the order should be (ON, OFF, ON, OFF etc) how do I do this for events with the exact same timestamp? Thanks

```
EVENT_ID             DATE_TIME                     ACTION
--------             -------------------           ------
1234                 22/02/2023 12:05:00           ON
1235                 22/02/2023 13:30:57           OFF
1236                 22/02/2023 20:15:05           OFF
1237                 22/02/2023 20:15:05           ON
```

Comment: Convert Action to a number with a calculation and use that calculated value for additional sort criteria. IIf(), If Then, Case - whatever teradata offers. What is the GUI you are programming in?

Comment: Seems odd Event_ID sequence doesn't coincide with the ON/OFF.

Comment: Alternatively, save Action as a number value then calculate to display string for report output.

Comment: The correct answer is to fix this in your database.  Use a timestamp that includes milliseconds. Fix the logic that generates the event id.  There is no logic that you could implement on this that would guarantee you are sorting correctly.